# Remove blurry background

Tags: imagemagick

I have downloaded a lot of photos from my phone where many of them have a blurry background, which I have created with an app a while ago. Unfortunately I no longer have the originals, so I would like to get rid of the blurry background I have added (to make them square for Instagram).

I searched for ways to do that, but I only find examples with single color background. I am wondering if there might be a way to crop an image alongside a "sharp" edge or something like this?

What I would like to do...
From this:

[image: From this]

To this:

[image: To this]

BTW: depending on the original aspect ratio the blur can be top and bottom or left and right.

Comment: What is your Imagemagick version and platform?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided your Imagemagick version and platform.  Code would be different.

Processing would be 1) apply laplacian to find what is not blurred, 2) stretch the contrast, 3) threshold, 4) apply morphology close to connect regions, 5) apply connected components processing to filter out small regions and find the bounding box of the largest white region, 6) crop the image with the given bounding box

Assume Imagemagick 7 on Unix-like platform.

Input

[image]

```
bbox=`magick burger.jpg \
-morphology convolve laplacian:1 \
-contrast-stretch 0x1% \
-auto-threshold otsu \
-morphology close disk:9 \
-type bilevel \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:keep-top=2 \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=100 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 burger_cleaned.png | grep "gray(255)" | awk '{print $2}'`
echo $bbox
magick burger.jpg -crop $bbox +repage burger_cropped.png
```

[image]

Adjust the contrast, morphology and area-threshold arguments as needed/desired.

For Imagemagick 6, replace magick with convert and replace auto-threshold otsu with a normal threshold of about 20%